# Find all ancestors by a certain id which is deep down a recursive hierarchy

Tags: algorithm

I want to get all ancestors of the Id 51 which are:
1,11,22,31,41.

I do not want an algorythm where I first find the object with Id 51 and then Traverse up the parent hierarchy.

I want to go recursively down the hierarchy and grab all ancestors.

But I guess that way the game is not played right? Because everytime I could grab an ancestors I CAN not know wether the next child is the Id 52. Is there any clever workaround?

```
 1
-11
 -21
 -22
  -31
   -41
    -51
  -32
  -33
 -23
-12
-13
```

**UPDATE**

@Jim Mischel asked how I find the object and show that code:

```
public static T FindChild<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selectorChildrenProperty, Predicate<T> condition) where T : class {

    if(source == default(T)) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source"); 
    }

    T t = default(T);
    foreach(T item in source) {
        if(condition(item)) {
            t = item;
            break;
        }
        else {
            t = selectorChildrenProperty(item).FindInHierarchy<T>(selectorChildrenProperty, condition);
            if(!Equals(t, default(T))) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

This will find an object with a certain property and return it.

Of course I could write a 2nd Generic method and start with that found object and traverse the hierarchy up until the parent is null but...

maybe there is a clever algo I dare to ask for...

someone more smart than I.

Comment: what kind of data structure is this?

Comment: Why isn't 21 considered an ancestor?

Comment: Is there a *tree* involved?

Comment: Show your code for finding the item, and we can probably show you how to modify it so that it returns the ancestors.

Comment: Looks like a stack could make it

Comment: Seems like you could return the current node from the recursion. Set a flag when you've found the item, and when the flag's set add the return value to a list. That would give you all the ancestors in reverse order.

Comment: @Dan W because an ancestor is not a sibling. Ancestors are parent, grand parent and so forth. 21 is not a grand grand parent from 51.

Comment: @angelatlarge Yes its a tree.

Comment: Why not just recurse *up* from 51, but only output the found node after you've recursed. You outputs will be in the specified order. I guess I just don't understand how it can be a *requirement* to recurse down the hierarchy.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Before I can recurse up (traverse) I need to know where 51 is...

Comment: @ALL I have updated my question with a code sample.

Comment: Please note that `all ancestors` is exactly the `path` from the root to the given node `51`.

Comment: This is very easy to do with a stack (push at the beginning of the function, pop before returning, if not found, or similar), but my C# skills are too rusty to code that up. It looks like you're currently going through the entire tree, it might be a better idea to have a [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) or hash table which links directly to the node in your structure and then traverse up from there or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible clever workaround is some rule which tells you where to find the children of the parent. For example in [binary search trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)s when you are looking at the parent you know which child will contain the node.  Without such rule you would have to replicate information about the children in the ancestors, which will recreate much of the information already stored in the tree.